# SetThreadContext modifies only the last 32 bits of RIP in x64

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, 64-bit

For an unknown reason, **SetThreadContext does not work as intended in an x64 process**. I intent to use it on a suspended thread to modify the instruction pointer and make the thread execute some shellcode. **Unfortunately, SetThreadContext seem to only modify the last 32 bits of the x64 instruction pointer RIP**.

To isolate the problem, I made the following small program that prompts the user for a thread ID to attach to, then if it is attached successfully to the thread the user can enter an address to modify the instruction pointer manually.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    DWORD tid = 0;
    cout << "Thread ID: ";
    cin >> dec >> tid;

    HANDLE hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, tid);
    if (hThread == NULL) {
        cout << "Failed." << endl;
        system("pause");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    DWORD64 newRip = 0;
    cout << "New RIP: 0x";
    cin >> hex >> newRip;

    CONTEXT tcNew;
    SecureZeroMemory(&tcNew, sizeof(tcNew));
    tcNew.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;
    tcNew.Rip = newRip;

    SuspendThread(hThread);
    SetThreadContext(hThread, &tcNew);
    ResumeThread(hThread);

    cout << "Done." << endl;
    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Now if I start another x64 process that I attach to a debugger and use a tool such as Process Hacker or Sysinternals' Process Explorer to get a running thread ID of this process, I can simply attach this program to the thread I want to modify and enter the address at which I want it to go execute.

I made the test with several program (some compiled with my Visual Studio and some x64 processes from my Windows, such as notepad or mspaint) and **if I set the new RIP to 0x1234567890ABCDEF then I get an Access violation executing location 0x0000000090ABCDEF**

Now this is interesting, it seems like **the most significant 32 bits of the RIP address are lost in the process for some reason** that I cannot explain.
I thought of some problem in the configuration of my Visual Studio project, so I have started from scratch again, but same thing. I also tried to install another IDE and compiler (Code::Blocks and MinGW64) but the problem remains the same for some reason.
More intriguing, **GetThreadContext works well, I successfully get the exact 64 bits of the address at which RIP is in a suspended thread.
Only SetThreadContext seems to be the problem.**

If you have any idea of why this happens, or any suggestion of experiments I could try to get me new ideas on how to solve this problem, please share without hesitation.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Most probably, 0x1234567890ABCDEF address is out of the bounds of the CS selector of your target process.

Comment: @Malkocoglu I also tried obviously to send the thread to an address where there is proper shellcode in an executable memory area and it does the same thing. In any case, the instruction pointer should point to the address I send it to, there is no reason why it should refuse, even if it is pointing to an address where there is nothing, it should point there and would trigger an exception on resume.

Comment: `SetThreadContext` 100% work correct for x64 too. in your code you not intialize SS and CS registers before call. first call `GetThreadContext` and only then modify `Rip` and call `SetThreadContext`. also `Rip` must have canonical form - *most significant 16 bits of any virtual address, bits 48 through 63, must be copies of bit 47*

Comment: yes, this exactly because you have `SegCs = 0;` change it to correct value `0x33` (much better call `GetThreadContext` first ) and you got exception at `0x0000567890abcdef` address. most significant 16 bits will be 0 due canonical normalization

Comment: if you change `Rip` to say `0x1234867890abcdef` you got exception at `0xffff867890abcdef`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @RbMm calling GetThreadContext on the CONTEXT I then use to edit the RIP solved the problem. I will read more about the role of this SegCs to understand the cause of this issue in more details.